# ionic Cordova iOS 13 gyroscope / device orientation issue

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, orientation, device, gyroscope

calling

```
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function (event) {
   console.log(event);  
});
```

won't work anymore without getting "DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission()" before the call, which is a new w3c implementation but doesn't work with ionic Cordova yet(?).

Any ideas?

Comment: you can try to use the Screen Orientation plugin from Ionic : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screen-orientation

Answer (score 2):

I answer it myself:

this is only basic, no handle to promt the iOS dialog to allow permission again included. If user once decided to "not allow" gyroscope there is no handling.

Right now within typescript it is not possible to call the JS function requestPermission(), so you simple would include a JS File with

```
var requestOrientationPermit = function() {
  DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission();
}
```

and then in the angular ionic ts file

```
declare var requestOrientationPermit : any;
// ...

// (in some typescript onclick event! call:)
requestOrientationPermit();

// ...
// later...
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function (event) {
  console.log(event);
```

`.`});

Comment: hi @maxxx, could you please tell me how exactly did you included the js file?

Comment: This was on an Angular Project. Put the JS Code in the index.html or include a JS file there. 

But the better solution is to use native gyroscope cordova plugin on ionic. It does not ask you to give permission for orientation devices.

Comment: it does not work anymore since ios 13... thats why i am searching for a fix

Comment: import { Gyroscope, GyroscopeOrientation, GyroscopeOptions } from '@ionic-native/gyroscope/ngx';
...
private gyroscrope: Gyroscope
...
this.gyroscope.getCurrent(options)
                        .then((orientation: GyroscopeOrientation) => {
                            var event = {
                                alpha: orientation.x,
                                beta: orientation.y,
                                gamma: orientation.z,
                            }
...


works still in iOS > 13

Comment: Seems gyroscope works , but DeviceMotion no.